# why can assembler work in advanced language

Tags: assembly

we know assembler is used to transfer advanced language into assemble language. So if we use advanced languages to achieve an assembler,who will assemble this assembler program?

Answer (score 2):

First, what you call "advanced language" is normally known as [high-level language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_language). Now, you say that it's assembler that translates code from a high-level language into assembly language. This is wrong: such a translator is actually called [*compiler*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler). After a compiler does the conversion of e.g. C++ code into assembly language, an [assembler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembler_(computing)#Assembler) does the conversion of the assembly-language code into machine code.

Comment: What you said is right. My puzzle is that a compiler  which achieved by high-level language also needs to be compiled when it runs, so who will compile this compiler, and does it achieved by high-level language?It seems that egg is early or chicken .

Comment: @shiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)

Comment: @shiki: [How was the first assembler for a new home computer platform written?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/3326), and related [When and why did high-level language compilers start targeting assembly language rather than machine code?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/14927)